# What's the used software in this animation?

Tags: video, editing, screenshot, visual-effects

Please take a look at http://www.howcast.com/videos/186055-How-To-Create-a-Knol

Is there software to do this kind of effect using screen shots and with similar quality?

Note this is not Adobe Flash.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that these presentations are custom made:

> Howcast works directly with brands, agencies, and organizations to create custom branded entertainment, innovative social media, and targeted rich-media campaigns.
>
> **Engage our creative and production team to conceive, create and deploy high quality, low-cost, short-form instructional video content for your business or organization.**

They make them in-house.

If you want to record your own videos you might want to try Camtasia.

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact an Adobe Flash video, but that has nothing to do with how it was made.  A video like that can be made using various tools and can then be published to any video format, among which the Flash video format is one.

Camtasia is a good tool for making screencasts but I don't think it has functionality to make the 3D screens and pans of application windows in the referenced video.  Despite it being "custom" or "self-made", I expect the people who made the video used some publicly available commercial or open-source software tool that made production of the video effects easier.  Sorry I don't know what software they might have used, but I'm also curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

It could be anything, heck, I could do that in [blender](http://www.blender.org/)! Just looking at a video like that cannot give you enough information to see what created it, things just don't work that way.

Comment: No, things don't necessarily work that way.  On the other hand, some effects that are "canned" and made easily producible by some certain piece of software are easily recognizable and give you a clue that often indicates the software that was used to produce the effect.  E.g., with Camtasia the particular way it can be set to produce a graphic circle in spots where a mouse button is being clicked make it clear to someone who's aware of it that Camtasia was probably used to produce the video.

Comment: Ah yes, I had not thought of that...another example would be the White-on-Navy-Blue captions which Windows Movie Maker defaults to and no one changes, not to mention the "Typewriter" effect for the animation of captions. But I was really meaning 3D animation like OP's video, which tends to be about the same regardless of software.